# Mapping CSV data in flutter

Tags: flutter, csv, mapping, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[Auto-complete search list](https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-auto-complete-search-list-a8dd192bd5f6)

How to parse csv data instead of json data as mentioned in this article. I am new to csv and I have trouble mappping csv data to a model list. I need to pass the csv list to autocomplete field in another package plz help me in mapping it to the model.

```
class Players {
  String keyword;
  int id;
  String autocompleteterm;
  String country;

  Players({
    this.keyword,
    this.id,
    this.autocompleteterm,
    this.country
  });

  factory Players.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Players(
        keyword: parsedJson['keyword'] as String,
        id: parsedJson['id'],
        autocompleteterm: parsedJson['autocompleteTerm'] as String,
        country: parsedJson['country'] as String
    );
  }
}

class PlayersViewModel {
static List<Players> players;
static Future loadPlayers() async {
    try {
      players = new List<Players>();
      String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/players.json');
      Map parsedJson = json.decode(jsonString);
      var categoryJson = parsedJson['players'] as List;
      for (int i = 0; i < categoryJson.length; i++) {
        players.add(new Players.fromJson(categoryJson[i]));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/csv This package looks promising